# Python break out of poll when key pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpiozero

Apologies for the newbie Python post, but a bit of Googling and I still can't find what I need.

I have the following Pi Hat; https://github.com/modmypi/Jam-HAT, ...and I'm using their docs to guide me; https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html

My idea is pretty simple;

- run script when button pressed
- wait for it to run, showing flashy lights whilst running
- if I press another button, stop/kill script

However, I'm stuck on the part where I need to stop the script with a button

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gpiozero
import subprocess
from signal import pause
from time import sleep

button1 = gpiozero.Button(18)
button2 = gpiozero.Button(19)
green1  = gpiozero.LED(16)
green2  = gpiozero.LED(17)
red1    = gpiozero.LED(5)
red2    = gpiozero.LED(6)
script  = ""
yellow1 = gpiozero.LED(12)
yellow2 = gpiozero.LED(13)

def kill_hello():
    global script
    script.kill()
    print("Killed PID: ", script.pid)
    red1.on()
    sleep(.5)
    red1.off()
    red2.on()
    sleep(.5)
    red2.off()

def say_hello():
    global script
    green1.on()
    sleep(.5)
    green1.off()
    green2.on()
    sleep(.5)
    green2.off()
    script = subprocess.Popen(['/home/kali/hello.sh'])
    print("Script PID: ", script.pid)
    while script.poll() is None:
        if not button2.when_pressed:
            green1.on()
            sleep(.5)
            green1.off()
            sleep(1)
        button2.when_pressed = kill_hello

print("Press Ctrl & C to Quit")

try:
    button1.when_pressed = say_hello
    pause()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print( "\n...Quit!")
```

I've tried a `try`/`except` where that `while` loop is, but that has also not worked (not like the `KeyboardInterrupt`). It doesn't recognise the button has been pressed, and I'm assuming because it's not within a valid catch/else/something block.

Any suggestions for a simple break out of loop, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is around a single process is hogging Python, thus creating multiple threads helped;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gpiozero
import subprocess
import time
import threading
from signal import pause

button1 = gpiozero.Button(18)
button2 = gpiozero.Button(19)
green1  = gpiozero.LED(16)
green2  = gpiozero.LED(17)
red1    = gpiozero.LED(5)
red2    = gpiozero.LED(6)
script  = ""
yellow1 = gpiozero.LED(12)
yellow2 = gpiozero.LED(13)
switch  = True

def blink():
    def run():
        while (switch == True):
            green1.on()
            time.sleep(.2)
            green1.off()
            time.sleep(.2)
            if switch == False:
                break
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()

def switchon():
    global switch
    global script
    switch = True
    print('switch on')
    script = subprocess.Popen(['/home/kali/hello.sh'])
    blink()

def switchoff():
    global switch
    global script
    print('switch off')
    script.kill()
    switch = False

try:
    button1.when_pressed = switchon
    button2.when_pressed = switchoff
    pause()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print( "\n...Quit!")
```